# GetActiveNotifications () method how use it to find a package?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, package-name

I know i can use this method: `GetActiveNotifications()` to get the active notifications in my notifications bar but i don't know why.. What i want exactly is check if a package name is present or not so then i can make a condition to read the notifications of specify app. I can get the package name in this way:

```
Log.i(TAG,"Package Name" + sbn.getPackageName());
```

but the problem is create the right method with all informations. Can anyone help me? Thanks